# Get distinct objects from list of dynamic objects

Tags: c#, dynamictype

I'm trying to return a distinct list of dynamic objects. 
The object that I am filtering on is of type `dynamic {System.Collections.Generic.List<object>}` with each of its indexed items being of type `object {System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject}`.

An example of the data structure is found below:

```
Model.Object
    - [0]
        - Property 1 (value: aaa)
        - Property 2 (value: 123)
        - Property 3 (value: a123)
    - [1]
        - Property 1 (value: bbb)
        - Property 2 (value: 456)
        - Property 3 (value: a456)
    - [2]
        - Property 1 (value: ccc)
        - Property 2 (value: 123)
        - Property 3 (value: a123)`
```

I have tried the following, but with no success:
`var distinctResults = ((List<object>)Model.Object).GroupBy(elem => elem.Property 2).Select(group => group.First());`

Any help please?

Comment: "... but with no success". Did it give you any data? If it did, what was wrong with it?

Comment: Hi, the following error was generated: ` 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Property 2' and no extension method 'Property 2' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found`

Comment: Most likely because you cast it to a `List<object>`, try `List<dynamic>` perhaps?

Comment: Worked! Thanks Lasse, please add it as an answer

Comment: Peet already did :) Just accept his answer, no need to add another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lasse V. Karlsen said, cast it to `List<dynamic>`